# Google analytics UA tracking code not working, functioning on analytics debugger and firebug

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

My Google analytics is showing the following message:

> Status: Tracking Not Installed
>   Last checked: Apr 19, 2015 9:44:04 AM PDT
>   The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web administrator must add the code to each page of your website.

My webpage is anthonychen.ca

I've tried: removing the www. on the admin section
I checked using the Google Analytics debugger on chrome; ran firebug, neither shows any error. The code I pasted is:

```
<script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-620xxxxx-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The analytics code needs to be added to very page.

If your website is just a static HTML website you will need to do this in every page. If your website is dynamic (developed with server side languages such as PHP, .net, etc) you will need to add the code to the "master" file and the analytics will automatically be added to every page.

Answer (score 0):

It generally takes between 24 and 48 hours for GA to begin to display data in the reports, the Real-Time views will become the first available to track yourself. Are these working now that the code has been on the site for a little while?

Comment: HI thank you for the reply, no it hasn't started to work yet. It still says tracking not installed

Comment: If you'd like we can check the code on the page to check for any issues with it there, make sure it is on the individual pages code and not just in one specific location. (unless it is a "master" file)

Comment: Hi Ryan, it's a single landing page